# How to do join operation on nested data for Postgresql

Tags: sql, database, string, postgresql, join

I have a bunch of tables which I'm looking to do a join operation on. They look something like this

Main Data

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| id | title | mainCategory |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 1  | xyz   | 1            |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 2  | zba   | 2            |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 3  | ync   | 3            |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

Sub Categories

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| ID | rowId | categoryID |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 7  | 1   | 1            |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 9  | 1   | 2            |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 10  | ync   | 3            |
+----+-------+--------------+
rowID is a foreign key that links a sub category to the main data
```

Category Table

```
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
| 1  | apples   |             
+----+-------+
| 2  | Bananas   |
+----+-------+
| 3  | Tomatoes   |
+----+-------+
```

Ideally I'll like to get the data nicely ordered like this if possible. I just need to have the subCategoryID and category value.

```
+----+-------+--------------+ --------------+
| id | title | mainCategory | SubCategory
+----+-------+--------------+ --------------+
| 1  | xyz   | 1            | (7 , Apples ), (9 , Bananas) |
+----+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 2  | zba   | 2            | Null
+----+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 3  | ync   | 3            | (10, Tomatoes )
+----+-------+--------------+--------------+
```

Any tips on how to do this would be great! Thank you so much.

Comment: Show the code that is throwing the error.

Comment: create table´s + insert for your question might be required, no way to join/group graphic-tables

Comment: your question looks like you need some sort of aggregation ... "(7 , Apples ), (9 , Bananas)" is hinting at that solution:
[String-Aggregation](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-string_agg-function/)

Comment: "rowID is a foreign key that links a sub category to the main data" -- I can see the third row `ync` matching, but not the first tow rows... how do they match?

Answer (score 0):

One option is joins and string aggregation. In Postgres, a lateral join comes handy for this:

```
select m.*, x.*
from main m
cross join lateral (
    select string_agg('(' || sc.id || ', ' || c.title || ')', ', ') subcategory
    from sub_category sc
    inner join category c on c.id = sc.category_id
    where sc.rowId = m.main_category
) x
```